# User role with if statement inside array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have been stuck here for 2 days, the problem is user role, the script I used has 3 user roles, (user, moderator, admin)"numeric" , with the current configuration, user role(USER) and admin role(Admin) works very well, but that of moderator is impossible to fix it. thanks for your help. here is the script

```
<?php if (empty($wo['user'])) {
    header("Location: " . Wo_SeoLink('index.php?link1=welcome'));
    exit();
}
$webmasterid = YOUR_WEBMASTERID;
$password = 'YOUR_SCRIPT_CHAT_PASSWORD';
$user = array(
    'username'=>$wo['user']['username'],
    'image'=>base64_encode($wo['user']['avatar']),
    'gender'=>$wo['user']['gender'],
    'role'=>($wo['user']['admin']==1)?'admin':'user', 
/* user role admin is =1,user role moderator is =2, and user role USER is =0
can i input here the if statement!!? if YES, HOW!! */
    'password'=>$password
);
$encrypted = file_get_contents("https://html5-chat.com/protect/".base64_encode(json_encode($user)));
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://html5-chat.com/script/<?=$webmasterid?>/<?=$encrypted?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
<?php exit();?>
```

Comment: Do you mean that `$wo['user']['admin']` is `0` for user, `1` for admin and `2` for moderator? If yes, then it's a very strange structure. If that's not what you mean, then you need to show us a proper example of what the different states actually looks like since it's very unclear. However, you can simply create a variable (something like `$role`) before you declare the array and set it to the correct value and use that in the array definition.

Comment: yes, for user is 0, for admin is 1 and for moderator is 2,  with this config, user and admin work wery well.

Comment: this is integration script for wowonder cms to html5 chat, as u can see the  role is under user array, becaus we can't define wich user role have to join on chat, can be one admin, one user or one moderator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put `if` inside array definitions. You could use nested ternaries (like: `$foo == 1 ? 'admin' : ($foo == 2 ? 'moderator' : 'user')` but these tend to be hard to read and easy to mess up so it's highly discouraged.

#### Alternative 1

You can set a `$role` variable before the array definition:

```
$role = 'user';
if ($wo['user']['admin'] == 1) {
    $role = 'admin';
} else if ($wo['user']['admin'] == 2) {
    $role = 'moderator';
}

// Now just use the $role variable
$user = array(
    ...
    'role' => $role, 
    ...
```

#### Alternative 2

Same as alternative 1, but with `switch/case`:

```
switch($wo['user']['admin']) {
    case 1:
        $role = 'admin';
        break;
    case 2:
        $role = 'moderator';
        break;
    default: 
        // Having this as default protects us from strangeness
        // if we would get something other than 0-2
        $role = 'user';
        break;
} 

// Now just use the $role variable
$user = array(
    ...
    'role' => $role, 
    ...
```

#### Alternative 3

Create an array with the different roles with the id as the key:

```
$roles = [
    'user',
    'admin',
    'moderator'
];

// Now you can fetch the role when defining the array by the id/key
$user = array(
    ...
    'role' => $roles[$wo['user']['admin']], 
    ...
```

Comment: no, u really help me, i have contact the support team for this script till 10 days and never answer, thanks you again